# Upgrading from Unity 2108.2 to 2018.4, huge apk size, scene is all white

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to upgrade a Unity 3D project from 2018.2.21 to 2018.4.30.
To upgrade I deleted the Library folder and used UnityHub to load the project with 2018.4.30.
The project build and ran in the Unity editor fine.
When I built the apk for Android it used to be 200mb but was now 4gb. The app contains a few 3D high res avatar models, and a few scenes which are loaded as streaming resources.

In the models changing the inspector setting "Legacy Blend Shape Normals" to true seemed to be the cause of the huge apk size, with that setting the apk in back to a normal size and I can run the apk on Android.

However the app loads and the scene loads, but the lighting on the avatars is very overexposed (too light), and the scene is not visible at all, just white.

Any idea what could cause this? We have upgrade other projects from 2018.2 to 2018.4 without these issues. Do I need to reexport the stream assets in 2018.4, or any idea what is going on?

When running in Unity the scene is fine, the avatars are still over exposed, but the scene is not white.
On Android the scene is just white.

Here is a screen shot from Unity 2018.2,
[image]

Here is a screen shot from Unity 2018.4,
[image]

Here is a screen shot of Unity 2018.8 on Android,
[image]

Seems like some kind of lighting issue maybe, but I have tried comparing the 2 projects and reverting any changes, but does not fix it.

Comment: kind of a long shot which is why I'm not posting a formal answer, but in the patch notes for the updated version (2018.4.30, https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/2018.4.30), the only android related change appears to be with the heap allocator.... maybe try reverting to old system (pass "-systemallocator" command line argument in UnityPlayerActivity)...? Assuming that doesn't help, have you tried to build to other sources in both versions to see if the size issue is just with android or the project as a whole? That might help narrow down the issue...

Comment: Have you run adb logcat to see if there are any errors/exceptions thrown by Unity when the scene is initialized? These might not be caught by the Unity console since it can happen before the profiler is connected `adb logcat -s Unity PackageManager dalvikvm DEBUG` might give you a clue.

Comment: Yes, connect app to logcat while running, no errors logged when the scenes load.

Comment: What happens if you create a new scene in your project, and build that new scene. Does it render the scene normally or will it also be all white? What do you have a light source in your scene, what happens if you turn it off, or add an unlit shader with a flat colour. Does that render the assigned colour?

Comment: Possible answer for "Scene is all white".
Maybe you searching an object in the hierarchy?

Comment: what about trying to upgrade to 2020 version?

Comment: have you tried running it with the attached debugger to see if there are any platform specific errors/warnings?

Comment: Yes, connect app to logcat while running, no errors logged when the scenes load.

Comment: We tried 2019, but had the same issue... and others...

Comment: Will try 2020, but can't see it being any better.

Comment: Will try a new scene. I did try reimporting the avatar model from scratch, but same lighting issue.

Comment: @James so, did updating to 2020 help?

Comment: @James What rendering pipeline are you using? And are you using post-processing?

Answer (score 1):

I give it a shot. That may help you:

> Window -> Lighting -> Settings -> Scene -> Environment Reflections ->
> Compression = Uncompressed.

By default, all images are compressed when added to your project, in that case you go:

> Edit -> Preferences -> General -> Compress Asset on Import = uncheck

and also:

> Edit -> Preferences -> GI Cache -> Cache Compression = uncheck

**Also set the source from "Color" to "Skybox".**

If it doesn't work, I will still help you till we are done ;)

Comment: thanks, this did not help, but I played with all the lighting settings there, and what worked was setting the source from "Color" to "Skybox", this fixed the lighting of the avatars, for the scenes I will check them next

Comment: Nice to hear. I was a bit further. Keep in mind the other settings I mentioned are also important. I added your troubleshooting to the answer. So if someone visit this post, he get's a compact solution. You are free to tick the answer as correct then. But only if you like to. Cheers :)